# ResponsiveMultiMenu - Get Menu SubMenu Lists to Open to Left

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

I am using ResponsiveMultiMenu  to handle my Responsive Website menuing and it is doing a good job for me.
But the SubMenu Lists drop-downs are opening/appearing to the Right or the primary menu drop-down.
My webpage would work better if I could figure out how to get them to open/appear to the Left.
I have looked over the ResponsiveMultiMenu.css code ( https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ResponsiveMultiMenu.css%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ), but cannot figure out:
1.  Is that where the change needs to occur?
2.  What change(s) need to occur?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I'll answer this one myself for anyone else's benefit.

Make the following change within the file  **ResponsiveMultiMenu.css**

```
/*  Mod to cause sub-menu dropdown to open to LEFT  */
/* --- Original Line ---*/
/*.rmm ul ul ul {position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0; width: 100%;}*/
/* --- Change To ---*/
.rmm ul ul ul {position: absolute; left: auto; right:100%; top:0; width: 100%;}
```

That worked for me.  Now the sub-menu dropdowns open to the Left which works for my overall layout much better.